# What is the use of Callout function in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, callouts

What is the use of Callout function in SharePoint 2013

Comment: Did you got the information from below answer or do you need some more information on it?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013, Microsoft has Introduced a new Framework to Create CallOuts that is somewhat similar to the Dialog Framework Introduced in SharePoint 2010.
The new **CalloutManager** class in `Callout.Js` (path – `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`) is responsible for Creating and editing Instances of a **CallOuts** in SharePoint 2013.

**CallOuts In SharePoint 2013**, are displayed only for Specific Lists and Libraries. For example, by default, CallOuts are displayed for Document Library,Assert Library,Task Lists etc and not for Custom Lists,Announcements Lists,Calendar List and Discussions Lists etc.

Refer below URL to implement it.

[CallOuts in SharePoint 2013](https://allaboutsharepoint13.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/callouts-in-sharepoint-2013/)